# how to read a leading zero number to dataframe in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I am reading an xml which has leading zero values(I'm not adding any schema as I am not sure about the schema of the data). but when i read using databricks spark xml lib, I am seeing the number is reading as long datatype and the leading zeros are no more added to it..

Is there any way to read the leading zero number as it is?

eg:
001234

### i am getting the result as
number

1234

### expected result is :
number

001234
The value is not a fixed length.

Comment: numbers do not start with 0. If you want to keep the leading 0, you need your value to be a string.

Comment: Yeah, my bad... expected result should be 001234 as string

Answer (score 0):

When you load without defining a schema, spark will try to "guess" the data type. This is called to infering the schema. To avoid that, you need the "tell" Spark the data type you are loading, in this case a String type. Something like:

```
my_schema = StructType([
    StructField("column1", StringType()),
    StructField("column2", DateType()),
    StructField("column3", IntegerType())
])

df = sqlContext.read \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")\
  .schema(my_schema)\
  .load("your_file.xml")
```

Comment: I have used the same, but i have unknown fields coming in the next xml file, and need to read them.. If i define the schema, i cannot cover those fields..is there any way to convert a single field while reading

Comment: Use ```.options("inferSchema" , "false")``` and all columns will be as type string

Comment: option("inferSchema", False) added this while reading the df, still no luck

Comment: my bad, i have used option instead options

Comment: Great, appreciate if you mark as answered

Comment: how does the schemaHints works, i tried like this but no difference
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").options(rowTag="tag").option("cloudFiles.schemaHints", "fieldvalue string").load(xmlfile)